# Cannot read property '...' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm having this code over here and I'm pretty sure I've passed the name properly but it still says as null:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var inj = document.getElementById("sterile").innerHTML;

function inject(data) {
    document.getElementById("sterile").innerHTML+=data;
}

function geth(elem) {
    return document.getElementById(elem).clientHeight;
}

inject( ".fullscreen { height:"+h+"px;}");

inject( ".headpad {padding-top:"+h-(geth("headwrap")/2)+"px;}");
```

I tried typing `geth("sterile")` onto the Chrome's devconsole and it returns properly but when I launch this through a file I always get `Uncaught TypeError....`

The error line was 10.

Comment: There's probably no element on the page with the id "headwrap". Thus `getElementById()` returns `null`.

Comment: There is! I tried using typing geth("headwrap") in the console and it works just fine.

Comment: Following on from @Pointy, if you could post your HTML as well, if its to long use pastebin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're including your javascript in the head tag, try including it just before the `</body>` tag instead. This ensures that the browser is aware of all elements by the time it parses your javascript.

Comment: oh gosh I just forgot about this!!! Thanks... Should've include this into onload instead of <head>

Comment: That would do it :) - but if you simply include at the end of the  page,  you won't need an onload event handler and it will fire as soon as possible. No delays for images etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mess around with the DOM, you should first wait for it to be ready. One way to do such is:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Your logic here
}, false);
```

Using `addEventListener` is also an Unobstrusive Javascript technique, which is a *way* good practice. You automatically get the advantage of wrapping your code inside a closure.